# How do i return a value from LINQ into a parameter? C#

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, return

So there's this method:

```
public void Method(A a, B b)
{
     OtherMethod(a, a.list.ForEach(o => {if(o.Status == Good){ return o};), b)
}
```

`OtherMethod()` needs 3 params. I want that `o` to put in the parameters, but I don't know how. Anybody knows how?

The actual code:

```
public void AddProduct(UserDTO u, ProductDTO p)
{
    if(CheckForCurrentOrder(u) != 0) //returns ID of order with status = "NotPaid"
    {
        CreateEmptyOrder(u);
        SetProductInOrder(u, u.Orders.ForEach(o => { if (o.Status == EnumsDTO.OrderStatus.NotPaid) { return o}; }), p);
    }

//rest of database code thats not relevant..
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "I want that o to put in the parameters" - could you give a full concrete example of what you're trying to achieve? It's hard to tell at the moment.

Comment: `a.list.Where(o => o.Status == Good)` will return an `IEnumerable<T>`, so if that's what the second argument type is, then this should work there. It would be helpful if you showed the method signature for `OtherMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq's [`First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_First__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) (or similar) method:

```
OtherMethod(a, a.list.First(o => o.Status == Good), b)
```

`First` will find the first item in `a.list` which matches the condition `o.Status == Good` (and will throw an exception is no items match this condition). You might want to use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) instead, which returns a default value if no items match this condition, of [`Single`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Single__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) which ensures that only a single item matches this condition.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get you your desired value by `Where()` and get it through `FirstOrDefault()` method:

```
var o = a.list.Where(o => o.Status == Good)).FirstOrDefault();
if (o != null) {
    OtherMethod(a, o, b)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming here  you want to pass "o" as parameter in "OtherMethod()"
for this you can create a new List as

```
 List<string> c = new List<string>();
```

and then add value of o to List c according to logic.

```
    c.Add()
//pass c as parameter to method
    OtherMethod(a, c, b);
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This would be also worth a shot, which checks all the objects, and executes them accordingly

```
u.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == EnumsDTO.OrderStatus.NotPaid)
        .Select(o => OtherMethod(a, o, b));
```